# Do I use the DNS Target or the heroku app domain for my CNAME Data?

Tags: heroku, dns, domain-name

When setting up a custom domain on Heroku, you are given a DNS Target.  My understanding is that this target should be entered into your domain provider's DNS CNAME data to correctly set up the custom domain.  However, most tutorials I see online have you do the herokuapp . com domain.  What's the difference, is one preferred over another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DNS target, as [the documentation says](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains):

> After you add a domain with the `heroku domains:add` command, you need to point your DNS provider at the DNS target provided by Heroku. You can view this DNS target with the `heroku domains` command (see [View existing domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#view-existing-domains) for details).

Always trust official documentation over third-party tutorials. Non-official documentation is much more likely to be outdated, or simply wrong.